How do I include a field in class constructor while keeping it optional on insert?
Constructor for EventAges:
class EventAges:
    def __init__(self, EventAgeName, EventAgeStart, EventAgeEnd):
        self.EventAgeName = EventAgeName
        self.EventAgeStart = EventAgeStart
        self.EventAgeEnd = EventAgeEnd

Its method:
def add_event_ages(self, event_ages):
    query = '''INSERT INTO EventAges (EventAgeId, EventAgeName, EventAgeStart, EventAgeEnd) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)'''
    values = ( event_ages.EventAgeName, event_ages.EventAgeStart, event_ages.EventAgeEnd)
    self.cursor.execute(query, values)
    self.connection.commit()
    EventAgeId = self.cursor.lastrowid
    return EventAgeId

Table EventAges includes EventAgeId but I did not include it in my class constructor since it is autoincremented. When querying I also want to retrieve EventAgeId, but it is not accepted because it is not in the class constructor.
How do I include EventAgeId in the class constructor while not requiring it on inserting into table?

Define your variable as self.EventAgeId = self.cursor.lastrowid. In your insert statement you should remove EventAgeId, because you said the table schema autoincrement the id.

You should redesign/expand things a bit. Do as @Hermann12 pointed out, then make the add_event method return the id of the inserted row. Then add another method that reads an event row by id

Thank you for the answers guys, also what I did was to include EventAgesId in the class constructor but set it to None making it
class EventAges:
def init(self, EventAgeName, EventAgeStart, EventAgeEnd, EventAgesId = None):
self.EventAgeName = EventAgeName
self.EventAgeStart = EventAgeStart
self.EventAgeEnd = EventAgeEnd
self.EventAgesId = EventAgesId
Then specified it in the function which order it is in the row and it worked

You do not need to include EventAgeId if that is an autoincrement integer ID. Here is an example similar to what I usually have in apps with sqlite. The example is derived from Flask Tutorial, where more details can be found.
Suppose my user table is defined and created by the following SQL code. I have autoincremented user_id, and the user data: username and password.
schema.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user
(
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
);


Now when I have a table, I can add a new row by inserting a tuple of form two strings (username, password). The user_id is not specified.
db.py
def create_user(username, password_hash):
    db = get_db()
    db.execute(
        "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)",
        (username, password_hash),
    )
    db.commit()


Note that in the above code, the db variable is an SQL connection (the class name is sqlite3.Connection).
